# What happens when mongodb deleteMany{()} is executed whitout query / empty query?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-collection

i wanted to ask what happens when collection.deleteMany{()} is executed in java without any query or empty string. Will it fail to execute (as in nothing is deleted) or will it drop the whole database?

Answer (score 0):

in `deleteMany()` when you execute without query it returns error
if you want to delete whole collection you could use `deleteMany({})`

Comment: Whoops, i mean deletemany({}) without string/empty

Comment: I said the all docs in collection to be deleted